# How do you measure if an interface change improved or reduced usability?

Tags: statistics, e-commerce, usability, testing-strategies

For an ecommerce website how do you measure if a change to your site actually improved usability?  What kind of measurements should you gather and how would you set up a framework for making this testing part of development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Multivariate testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_testing) and reporting is a great way to actually measure these kind of things.

It allows you to test what combination of page elements has the greatest conversion rate, providing continual improvement on your site design and usability.

[Google Web Optimiser](http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer) has support for this.

Comment: Multivariate testing is what you would use to classify interfaces when you have already made measurements. That leaves open the question of the measurement itself...

Comment: For some reason I had this notion that Web Optimizer was only for people advertising with Google.  Glad you linked to it so I could correct my bad assumption!

Answer (score 1):

Similar methods that you used to identify the usability problems to begin with-- usability testing. Typically you identify your use-cases and then have a lab study evaluating how users go about accomplishing certain goals. Lab testing is typically good with 8-10 people.

The more information methodology we have adopted to understand our users is to have anonymous data collection (you may need user permission, make your privacy policys clear, etc.) This is simply evaluating what buttons/navigation menus users click on, how users delete something (i.e. changing quantity - are more users entering 0 and updating quantity or hitting X)? This is a bit more complex to setup; you have to develop an infrastructure to hold this data (which is actually just counters, i.e. "Times clicked x: 138838383, Times entered 0: 390393") and allow data points to be created as needed to plug into the design.

Answer (score 1):

To push the measurement of an improvement of a UI change up the stream from end-user (where the data gathering could take a while) to design or implementation, some simple heuristics can be used:

- Is the number of actions it takes to perform a scenario less?  (If yes, then it has improved).  Measurement: # of steps reduced / added.
- Does the change reduce the number of kinds of input devices to use (even if # of steps is the same)?  By this, I mean if you take something that relied on both the mouse and keyboard and changed it to rely *only* on the mouse or *only* on the keyboard, then you have improved useability.  Measurement: Change in # of devices used.
- Does the change make different parts of the website consistent? E.g. If one part of the e-Commerce site loses changes made while you are not logged on and another part does not, this is inconsistent.  Changing it so that they have the same behavior improves usability (preferably to the more fault tolerant please!).  Measurement: Make a graph (flow chart really) mapping the ways a particular action could be done.  Improvement is a reduction in the # of edges on the graph.
- And so on... find some general UI tips, figure out some metrics like the above, and you can approximate usability improvement.

Once you have these design approximations of user improvement, and then gather longer term data, you can see if there is any predictive ability for the design-level usability improvements to the end-user reaction (like: Over the last 10 projects, we've seen an average of 1% quicker scenarios for each action removed, with a range of 0.25% and standard dev of 0.32%).

Answer (score 0):

The first way can be fully subjective or partly quantified: user complaints and positive feedbacks. The problem with this is that you may have some strong biases when it comes to filter those feedbacks, so you better make as quantitative as possible. Having some ticketing system to file every report from the users and gathering statistics about each version of the interface might be useful. Just get your statistics right.

The second way is to measure the difference in a questionnaire taken about the interface by end-users. Answers to each question should be a set of discrete values and then again you can gather statistics for each version of the interface.

The latter way may be much harder to setup (designing a questionnaire and possibly the controlled environment for it as well as the guidelines to interpret the results is a craft by itself) but the former makes it unpleasantly easy to mess up with the measurements. For example, you have to consider the fact that the number of tickets you get for each version is dependent on the time it is used, and that all time ranges are not equal (e.g. a whole class of critical issues may never be discovered before the third or fourth week of usage, or users might tend not to file tickets the first days of use, even if they find issues, etc.).

Comment: Wouldn't a questionaire violate the ["Don't listen to users"](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20010805.html) usability guideline?

Answer (score 0):

Torial stole my answer.  Although if there is a measure of how long it takes to do a certain task.  If the time is reduced and the task is still completed, then that's a good thing.

Also, if there is a way to record the number of cancels, then that would work too.

Comment: Sorry to steal.  I'll give you an upvote to make up for it :-)